# cross validating a train set where the class variable has a different distribution than the actual population

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

(noob in ML, be patient) 
I want to test the performance of my scikit-learn SVMLinear classifier. My train-set has a different class distribution than the actual population, but my test-set is a representative, and distributes like the actual population.

I noticed that there's a class-weight parameter, and I want to try giving my classifier the actual population distribution, and see if it helps it perform better.

However - as my train-set distribution is different, so will be my validation set, right? So should I expect an improvement on the validation, or must I use my test-set to see the improvement? And if so - isn't it against the rules to calibrate using the test-set which will lead to burning the test-set or overfitting?

I've thought about bootstrap re-sampling of my train-set: making it distribute the same as the general population, and only then training and validating my model. Is this a good solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't look so noob,;-). I think your ideas are right and this is how I would go about solving the problem. I would only add that in ML many things are dataset/algo dependent so only you will be able to find out the definitive answer to your questions. And of course, if you use the test set then not even you will know.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have some good ideas which are mostly worth trying. The answers mostly depend on the application and the size of your train/test set.

It is against the rules to calibrate based on test set and again use the whole test set for evaluation. However, if your test set is large enough, you can always divide your test set to two sets: validation set, and actual test set. Then, your final evaluation will be based on a smaller test set, which might be still acceptable depending on the application.

For your training set that you believe it has different class distribution than the actual population, there might be several things worth trying. Usually the most acceptable approach is to use a classifier that can handle these differences (usually with fewer parameters to avoid over-fitting). There is a whole topic of classification and regression on skewed datasets that you can look through. Other than the classifier, provided that you did not derive the actual population from your test set, the methods below might help too:
1- One of them can be (as you said) bootstrap re-sampling in case that your training set is large enough for that. 
2- Another approach can be generating more training samples by adding some noise to the current samples of the training set. For example if you are classifying images of birds, you can randomly make images darker or brighter, or randomly move them a few pixels to the sides or up and down (select values randomly in a small enough range). This way, you can add to the training set in a way to get the desired distribution.